# How do I get bandwidth and received signal strength information using Java?

Tags: java, windows, bandwidth, rssi, iperf

I'm on a Windows machine using Java. I would like to get my bandwidth and received signal strength (RSSI) readings.

On my Mac, I use the iperf and tcpdump utilities respectively.

1) I can't seem to get RSS readings from winpdump

2) I'm not sure how to call these utilities from the Java environment

Would it be easy to resolve these issues, or is it easier if I simply switch over to a *nix platform to do this?

Comment: No idea about tools for your request; but to run a command, seach for Java and "ProcessBuilder".